# How can I improve my Ruby practices with array and hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have `array1`, which is an array of hashes, and `array2`, which is an array of integers. `array1.size` and `array2.size` are `10`. I want to add each element in `array2` to its corresponding hash in `array1`. So `array2[0]` would be added to the hash at `array1[0]`.

I coded it like:

```
for x in 0..array1.size
 array1[x][:array2_value] = array2[x]
end
```

I feel like there is a clean way of doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want suggestions for improving your coding style, and to make it more idiomatic, then you should ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: Show sample input arrays, and an example of the desired output.

Comment: `0...array1.size` by the way

Comment: Definitely a question for the code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
array1.each_with_index { |h,i| h[:array2_value] = array2[i] }
```

Another:

```
array1.zip(array2).each { |h,v| h[:array2_value] = v }
```

If `array1` is not to be altered:

```
array1.map.with_index { |h,i| h[:array2_value] = array2[i] }

array1.zip(array2).map { |h,v| h[:array2_value] = v }
```

Comment: Why `map` when you don't care about the return value? `array1.each.with_index { ... }` would be sufficient if you're planning on modifying `array1` in-place.

Comment: Good point, μ. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
array1.map.with_index{|h, i| h.merge(array2_value: array2[i])}
```

or

```
array1.each_with_index{|h, i| h.merge!(array2_value: array2[i])}
```